# add \addcontentsline command doesn't work

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am using TeXmaker for my editor and I am trying to add contents to my table of contents. For some chapters it does work, and for others just won't. I am familiar with command `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Name}`. Here is my code:

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Predgovor}      
\input{tex/uvod}\newpage  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Predgovor}  
\chapter{Kriptovalute}  
\input{tex/kriptovalute}\newpage  
\chapter{Pregled osnovnih definicija i teorema}  
\input{tex/teorija}\newpage  
\chapter{Podaci}  
\input{tex/podaci}\newpage    
\chapter{Model vrednovanja kapitala (CAPM)}  
\input{tex/CAP}\newpage  
\chapter{Grejnd"zerov test}  
\input{tex/grejndzer}\newpage  
\chapter*{Zaklju"cak}  
\input{tex/zakljucak}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Zaklju"cak}  
\chapter*{Dodatak}  
\input{tex/prilozi}\newpage  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dodatak}



\end{document}
```

And after double build I receive:

[image]

There is chapter 'Zakljucak' and 'Predgovor', however there isn't chapter 'Dodatak'. Also every other `chapther*` after 'Zakljucak' doesn't appear.

Does anybody has an advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by making your example compilable and self-contained (a MWE).

Comment: `\addcontentsline` must be on a page which has some text. Why are you using them after the \input commands instead of directly behind the \chapter*? All the page numbers will be wrong if the text gets longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it right after the `\chapter*{}` command:

```
\chapter*{Dodatak} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dodatak}
\input{tex/prilozi}\newpage
```

Comment: You're welcome :) please remember to mark the answer as accepted (green check) once you find a solution that works for you.